# SAPUI5 Smart field not working

Tags: sapui5

I realized smart field is not working properly in versions 1.38-1.48.
If you have a big model with ca 30 fields, then smart field instantiation fails.
As a result only some of the smart fields do instantiate and has values.
(By every application refresh these are different fields).

Have you faced such issue already and how did you proceed?

SAP Support seems to be overwhelmed with fiori issues, so I stopped reporting issues there.

Update for SAP Fiori Crew:
I just tested the issue using Stable Ids, the same error is present.
Here is the example of our xml file:

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
                         xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                         xmlns:smartField="sap.ui.comp.smartfield" xmlns:smartForm="sap.ui.comp.smartform">
    <smartForm:SmartForm
      id="smartForm"
      editTogglable="false"
      editable="{LockInformation>/locked}"
      flexEnabled="false">
      <smartForm:Group>
        <smartForm:GroupElement>
          <smartField:SmartField
            id="stableId1"
            value="{main>description}"
            editable="true"
            />
        </smartForm:GroupElement>
      </smartForm:Group>
    </smartForm:SmartForm>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

And then this fragment is used inside of our xml view.
This is quite a simple case and can be reproduced easily, as there is no additional javascript for it.
Just remember to have model with around 20 fields declared same way as here in the fragment, add them to fragment too (I didn't do it to keep it small and simple) and use slow backend.

Update 2: a colleague found that there is a asynchronous execution of methods initialize and some other one which update the bindings. Depending on which one finishes first, smart field is either working or not. As every time I start application a random set of fields is broken/ working, we consider it to be a timing issue..

PD. Please let me know if you have found this issue and in which version it can be fixed..

Comment: Are you using Stable ID’s as mentioned [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/f51dbb78e7d5448e838cdc04bdf65403)?

Would it be possible for you to create an example in a tool like https://plnkr.co/ so we can debug the issue?

Comment: You mention to “use slow backend”.
Is there a specific reason for that?
Does it work with a fast backend?

Comment: Can you give a rough estimate how long it takes for your backend to respond?
Is it rather 5 seconds or 5 minutes?

Have you checked your backend for performance improvements?
Most of the time, bad performance is caused by unnecessary or expensive database calls.
You might be able to check on this with SQL Trace (ST05) in the backend.
This might only avoid a timing issue, not solve it.